# pdo WHERE IN checkboxes + multiselect

Tags: php, pdo, where-in

EDITED ON FEB. 11th, 2015 -11h38

I've spent hours looking for the right solution without achieving my goal. I just want to have the selected values of my multiselect[] and checkboxes[] read in my WHERE IN requests.
I've been trying for hours different solutions but I'm still utterly stuck.

Thanks for your help

```
$secteur_searched="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['secteur_searched']) AND is_array($_REQUEST['secteur_searched']))
   { foreach ($_REQUEST["secteur_searched"] as $selectedOption)        
     $secteur_searched.=$selectedOption.",";  
   }

if ($secteur_searched)
   { $secteur_searched = rtrim($secteur_searched, ',');
     $where[] = "j.job_secteur IN (:job_secteur) " ;
     $param[':job_secteur']= $secteur_searched;  
     var_dump($secteur_searched); // returns (1,2,3)
   }

if (!empty($where)) 
   { $query.= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
   }

 $query.= " ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC"; 
 $sth =$marInterim ->prepare($query);
 $sth->execute($param);

 $compte = $sth->fetchAll();
 $nb_resultats = count($compte); 
 $errors['nb_resultats_recherche'] = $nb_resultats; // ok (for ajax)

/********************/
 if ( !empty($_REQUEST['afficher_x_resultats']))
    { $per_page=$_REQUEST['afficher_x_resultats']; 
    }
 else {$per_page=10; }

/* Results per page */
$nb_pages = ceil($nb_resultats/$per_page);  
$current_page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) && ($_REQUEST['page'] > 0) && ($_REQUEST['page'] <= $nb_pages) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
$start = ($current_page-1)*$per_page;    

$query2= $query." LIMIT $start,$per_page "; 
$sth2 =$marInterim ->prepare($query2); 
$sth2-> execute($param); 
//print_r($sth2->errorInfo());

 while($datos= $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  { $en_date_insertion=$datos['job_date_insertion'];      
 $explode_insertion= explode("-", $en_date_insertion);
 $date_insertion_fr = $explode_insertion[2]."-".$explode_insertion[1]."-".$explode_insertion[0];         
 $job_id= $datos['job_id'];
 $job_intitule= strtoupper($datos['job_intitule']);
 $job_ville = $datos['ville_nom'];
 $job_cp = $datos['cp'];
    echo 'hello';        
echo "
                                   <div class='offers btns'>
                                   <a class='link_vers_offre' href='job_offer_detail.php?job_id=$job_id'>
                                   <table id='table_liste_des_offres'>
                                   <tr>
                                   <td class='liste_intitule'> " .$job_intitule." </td>
                                   <td class='liste_ref'>Offre n°" .$job_id."   du   ".$date_insertion_fr ." </td>
                                   <td class='liste_ville'> ".$job_cp. " ".$job_ville." </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   </table>
                                   </a>
                                   </div>
                                 ";
  }
```

Comment: function parms (once corrected) returns : `SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN ('1,2,3,4,5,6,13') ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC LIMIT 0,10`

Comment: I found that, and understand that all values contained in an array must be quoted, but I don't know how to match the following piece of code with mine.    `$idlist = array('260','201','221','216','217','169','210','212','213'); 
$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($idlist)-1) . "?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `foo` WHERE `id` IN ($questionmarks)");`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the html you're using. So lets say you have to following form which consists of a multiple select, checkbox list and a button.

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" method="POST">
    <select name="secteur_searched[]" id="secteur_searched" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="secteur_searched_1" selected>secteur_searched_1</option>
        <option value="secteur_searched_2">secteur_searched_2</option>
        <option value="secteur_searched_3" selected>secteur_searched_3</option>
        <option value="secteur_searched_4">secteur_searched_4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type_de_contrat[]" value="type_de_contrat_1" checked="checked" />type_de_contrat_1
    <input type="checkbox" name="type_de_contrat[]" value="type_de_contrat_2" checked="checked" />type_de_contrat_2
    <input type="checkbox" name="type_de_contrat[]" value="type_de_contrat_3" />type_de_contrat_3
    <input type="submit" value="POST VALUES" id="cmd" name="cmd"/>
</form>
```

If you wish to access all the checkbox/multiselect values `posted`, you need to add `[]` at the end of value you have specified in `name` attribute of the object. Such as

```
<select name="secteur_searched[]"></select>
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type_de_contrat[]" />
```

Here is how you access the posted values on server side.

**Multiselect**

```
foreach ($_POST["secteur_searched"] as $selectedOption)
  echo $selectedOption."<br/>";
```

**Checkboxes**

```
foreach ($_POST["type_de_contrat"] as $selectedCheckbox)
  echo $selectedCheckbox."<br/>";
```

Full code to print out the values when the form is posted

```
if (isset($_POST["cmd"]))
{
  if (isset($_POST["secteur_searched"]))
  {
    foreach ($_POST["secteur_searched"] as $selectedOption)
      echo $selectedOption."<br/>";
  }

  if (isset($_POST["type_de_contrat"]))
  {
    foreach ($_POST["type_de_contrat"] as $selectedCheckbox)
      echo $selectedCheckbox."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Next step is to construct the parameters to be used by `pdo` object. Here is an example code.

```
if (isset($_POST["cmd"]))
{
    $secteur_searched=""; //$param[':job_secteur']
    $type_de_contrat_searched=""; //$param[':type_de_contrat']
    if (isset($_POST["secteur_searched"]))
    {
      foreach ($_POST["secteur_searched"] as $selectedOption)
        $secteur_searched.=$selectedOption.",";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["type_de_contrat"]))
    {
        foreach ($_POST["type_de_contrat"] as $selectedCheckbox)
            $type_de_contrat_searched.=$selectedCheckbox.",";
    }

    if ($secteur_searched)
      $secteur_searched = rtrim($secteur_searched, ','); //get rid of the "," at the end 

    if ($type_de_contrat_searched)
      $type_de_contrat_searched= rtrim($type_de_contrat_searched, ','); //get rid of the "," at the end

   echo "type_de_contrat_searched:".$type_de_contrat_searched."<br/>secteur_searched:".$secteur_searched;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I suppose the problem you have is to access posted values. Let me know if that's not the case.

**EDIT 2**

I'm not sure if you tried this, so I'll put it down anyway. Check if your parameter bindings are correct with

```
$sth2->debugDumpParams();
```

right after you perform

```
$sth2->execute($param);
```

**EDIT 3**

Apparently `debugDumpParams` is not printing out the values of the parameters.

> This function doesn't print parameter values despite the documentation
>   says it does. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52384 (filed back in
>   2010).

Found one useful function in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) page as follows

```
function parms($string,$data) {
    $indexed=$data==array_values($data);
    foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
        if(is_string($v)) $v="'$v'";
        if($indexed) $string=preg_replace('/\?/',$v,$string,1);
        else $string=str_replace(":$k",$v,$string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

(Perhaps you already know that one) Use it to display prepared sql like this

```
print parms($query2,$param); //query,your parameter array
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, Ozgur Bar.

Oops I didn't know that typing Enter would post the message. Let me finish it. I'll be back in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: and what do you see when you `echo $query;` before `$sth =$marInterim ->prepare($query);`?

Comment: If I select all of my possible values for secteur_searched :
$query = SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,13,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,7,17,18) ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC

Comment: looks fine to me. anything in `print_r($sth->errorInfo());`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) - Great information ! 
What am i supposed to understand ? 
Thanks again

Comment: lol and do you see anything when you put `echo "entered";` in `while($datos= $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){}` if not make sure your query returns any result (simply run the query in phpmyadmin or something like that). if it does try `print_r($marInterim->errorInfo());` this time.

Comment: Yes LOL !!! or better said CRYING OUT LOUD - Well it depends. I have other inputs which I check the same way ( if !empty(input)) {$where[]=.. ; $param= ;}   and in what's for input type=text, I get results, even with j.job_descriptif LIKE CONCAT('%', :job_descriptif, '%').  But if I echo 'hello'; within my secteur_searched while loop , hello doesn't appears..

Comment: okay, but do you see any result when you run the following query directly in mysql -> `SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,13,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,7,17,18) ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC`

Comment: I didn't talk about that piece of code earlier, because It when typing in my search fields a keyword to be found in the job description or a job_title, I got  the right outputs displayed.... So I thought the problem was only located in the WHERE IN part... Hope u excuse me :)

Comment: If i echo $query and $query2, after having chosen a search by keyword, I get :QUERY1 = "
SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_descriptif LIKE CONCAT('%', :job_descriptif, '%') ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC "________________
$query2 = SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_descriptif LIKE CONCAT('%', :job_descriptif, '%') ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: But if I do the same by selecting a job_secteur , I get for QUERY1 : ,SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN (:job_secteur) ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC ______________________________________________________
$query2 = SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN (:job_secteur) ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC LIMIT 0,10

Answer (score 0):

You supposed well, my select and checkboxes name contain [] :

```
 <select multiple="multiple" name="secteur_searched[]" size="8">
  <option value="12">Informatique - Technologie de l'Information</option>
  <option value="14">Logistique - Manutention - Transport</option>
// and so on ...
</select>

 <input type="checkbox" name="type_de_contrat[]" value="CDI" >
 <input type="checkbox" name="type_de_contrat[]" value="CDD" >
```

and so on...

When I try your method (thank u!), which seems correct, I don't have any return from the data base. (the only input that I fill in for test is the multiselect).

```
   $secteur_searched="";

   if (!empty($_REQUEST['secteur_searched']) AND is_array($_REQUEST['secteur_searched']))
      { foreach ($_REQUEST["secteur_searched"] as $selectedOption)        
        $secteur_searched.=$selectedOption.",";  
      }

  if ($secteur_searched)
     { $secteur_searched = rtrim($secteur_searched, ',');
       $where[] = "j.job_secteur IN (:job_secteur) " ;
       $param[':job_secteur']= $secteur_searched;  
       var_dump($secteur_searched); // returns (1,2,3)
     }

 if (!empty($where)) 
    { $query.= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    }

 $query.= " ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC"; 

 $sth =$marInterim ->prepare($query);
 $sth->execute($param);

 while($datos= $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  { $en_date_insertion=$datos['job_date_insertion'];      
     $explode_insertion= explode("-", $en_date_insertion);
     $date_insertion_fr = $explode_insertion[2]."-".$explode_insertion[1]."-".$explode_insertion[0];         
     $job_id= $datos['job_id'];
     $job_intitule= strtoupper($datos['job_intitule']);
     $job_ville = $datos['ville_nom'];
     $job_cp = $datos['cp'];
echo "
                                       <div class='offers btns'>
                                       <a class='link_vers_offre' href='job_offer_detail.php?job_id=$job_id'>
                                       <table id='table_liste_des_offres'>
                                       <tr>
                                       <td class='liste_intitule'> " .$job_intitule." </td>
                                       <td class='liste_ref'>Offre n°" .$job_id."   du   ".$date_insertion_fr ." </td>
                                       <td class='liste_ville'> ".$job_cp. " ".$job_ville." </td>
                                       </tr>
                                       </table>
                                       </a>
                                       </div>
                                     ";

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function only returns

SELECT * FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN (:job_secteur) ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC LIMIT 0,10

```
function parms($query2,$param) {
$indexed=$param==array_values($param);
foreach($param as $k=>$v) {
    if(is_string($v)) $v="'$v'";
    if($indexed) $query2=preg_replace('/\?/',$v,$query2,1);
    else $query2=str_replace(":$k",$v,$query2);
}
return $query2;
} print parms($query2,$param);
```

---

Then,  $sth2->debugDumpParams();

[186] SELECT - FROM marinterim_job_offers j JOIN marimmo_villes v ON v.ville_id =j.job_ville WHERE j.job_secteur IN (-job_secteur) ORDER BY j.job_date_insertion DESC LIMIT 0,10 Params- 1 Key- Name- [12] -job_secteur paramno=-1 name=[12] --job_secteur- is_param=1 param_type=2

---

I've noticed that if I choose only 1 option at the time in my MultiSelect, I get the corresponding results... Ex: option value='5' -> returns the results corresponding to job_secteur 5..

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="secteur_searched[]" .../>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to change `$query2=str_replace(":$k",$v,$query2);` to `$query2=str_replace("$k",$v,$query2);` since you already have ":" in the keys. ps: why do you keep posting answers instead of updating the question? you're making it harder for the people to track.

Comment: Ok ok, maybe I can update my post n°1 and delete all the other ones. Thanks for pointing that / your suggestion.